# Exception when running ChromeDriver with WebDriverManager in maven project

Tags: maven, selenium-chromedriver, gauge, webdrivermanager-java, getgauge

I am getting an exception when trying to open the ChromeDriver using WebDriverManager in a Maven project.

The framework I am planning is tended to pull the ChromeDriver from WebDriverManager after adding the dependency in the pom.xml and is intended to use Gauge to perform the tests.

The error occurs at the moment it tries to create a new instance for the ChromeDriver when running the tests.

Here is the exception:

```
 Error Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter;
  Stacktrace: 
  org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:64)
  org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
  org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
  org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
  org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
  org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:255)
  org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
  org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:138)
  org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
  org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
  org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
  StepTests.setupTest(StepTests.java:26)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.MethodExecutor.execute(MethodExecutor.java:38)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.HooksExecutor$TaggedHookExecutor.executeHook(HooksExecutor.java:102)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.HooksExecutor$TaggedHookExecutor.execute(HooksExecutor.java:88)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.HooksExecutor.execute(HooksExecutor.java:45)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.processor.MethodExecutionMessageProcessor.executeHooks(MethodExecutionMessageProcessor.java:65)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.processor.SpecExecutionStartingProcessor.process(SpecExecutionStartingProcessor.java:32)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.connection.MessageDispatcher.dispatchMessages(MessageDispatcher.java:89)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.GaugeRuntime.dispatchMessages(GaugeRuntime.java:104)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.GaugeRuntime.access$100(GaugeRuntime.java:36)
  com.thoughtworks.gauge.GaugeRuntime$2.run(GaugeRuntime.java:85)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When running this code:

```
import com.thoughtworks.gauge.*;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.gauge.Step;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;


public class StepTests {
//Holds the WebDriver instance
private WebDriver webDriver;

@BeforeSuite
public static void initializeDriver(){
    ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
}

@BeforeSpec
public void setupTest(){
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
}

--test code--



    @AfterSuite
    public void closeDriver(){
        if (webDriver != null) {
            webDriver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Please inform me if there is something more you need to know to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have a version conflict in Guava. Selenium WebDriver (not WebDriverManager) depends transitively of a given version of Guava, and it seems you are using another one in your project. I would use the latest versions of both.

Comment: The current version of Guava is guava-21.0.jar if this helps.

Comment: Is there a workaround I would do meanwhile? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, working for me after adding the guava dependency :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
<artifactId>guava</artifactId>
<version>27.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[1st Possible Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54764263/4182343)**

**2nd Possible Solution**

Refer this answer only if the problem is not fixed with the **1st Solution**.

I have faced this issue and found no accepted answers on SO. I have figured this out by reading it on a non-SO link and pasting it here for future references.

**We need to figure out the exact problem first.**

If you are using IntelliJ or Eclipse, you need to go to the Run/Debug Configurations, and add a VM argument,

```
-ea -verbose:class
```

Now, re-run your test.
This will start printing out the classes and the jars from which those classes are being imported and used. In your specific case, if you search for **SimpleTimeLimiter**, you will see the package from which it is imported.

Since, there has been a conflict of package versions, this error has come up. **One jar dependency would be referring to an earlier **guava** version and this jar would be present early in the classpath. This will avoid the intended class-path to be used.**
To be more precise, there would be some package which is importing **guava** earlier than the one which you have written in your pom.xml.

**How is that possible?**

Let us assume, yours is a project which imports a package **dog-2.0.jar** and **animal-2.0.jar**. Now, you might be unaware that **dog-2.0.jar** internally imports **animal-1.0.jar**. So, owing to this dependency of imports, JVM will import a class named **Animal.class** which would be coming from **animal-1.0.jar** instead of the **Animal.class** you / your project is expecting from **animal-2.0.jar**.

**And then?**

JVM will get the reference of **Animal.class** even before it reaches your intended import of **animal-2.0.jar**. Hence, the order in which the jar files are being imported (class-path) will un-intentionally mess with this transitive dependency.

**What can I do?**

You can right-click on your project in INtelliJ and something similar for Eclipse. Click on

```
Open Module Settings -> Click on Dependencies
```

You will get the list of jars being imported here. You can re-arrange the order of the jars. You can push **dog-2.0.jar** right below your **animal-2.0.jar** dependency. This will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing the version of `guava` dependency in pom.xml to `23.0`.

If it is still not working for you, try changing the version of `gson` dependency in pom.xml to `2.8.2` or `2.8.5`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```